# Conditional Data Validation In SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a situation where table has two main columns DataFieldName & DataFieldValue along with some identifier such as OrderNumber.

Now in DataFieldName there is value named as "OrderDate" and respective dates are coming in DataFieldValue.

But some of the value for "OrderDate" are coming as non date values. I need to validate such non date value based on the condition where DataFieldName has value as "OrderDate" then validate the DataFieldValue for valid date in SSIS.

Comment: I would suggest you fix your data model. As it is now, it's more suitable for a noSQL database or maybe as a non-validated JSON.

Comment: First of all, you can add a conditional split and pass all rows with "OrderDate" on to a separate handling task. Then you could either try to add a datatype conversion and redirect all rows, where the conversion fails, to a separate output. Or you can add a transformation script component in your data flow and perform the check on correct date value there and again redirect faulty rows to another output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your data using a `Conditional Split` :

[image]

or a query with a condition if you are using SQL :

```
SELECT DataFieldName, DataFieldValue FROM yourTable
WHERE DataFieldName LIKE 'OrderDate'
```

If you are using SQL Server :

```
SELECT   
    CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(date, DataFieldValue) IS NULL   
    THEN 'Cast failed'  
    ELSE 'Cast succeeded'  
END AS Result 
FROM yourTable
```

If you are using Oracle :

```
SELECT cast(DataFieldValue AS NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) FROM yourTable
```

Or, you can use a `Data Conversion Transformation` component :

[image]

Then you can redirect the output to a flat file for example :
[image]